# pointed internal NLB with public domain

Tags: dns, internals, nlb

My requirement is I want to access AWS private resources using a private hosted zone.
The domain name would be HTTPS so for that I have to install SSL on a private hosted zone.
There are two option
1). Use AWS Private CA which is costly at $400/month.
2). Generate Custom SSL Certificates which is complicated.
My application is on the EKS cluster.
How can do that task easily?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.

You can use your public domain for internal NLB and use AWS ACM for SSL.
After pointing public domain it will not access from the internet, only can access inside the AWS VPC.